# Does C#.NET have any data structure that satisfies the following properties?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to solve a problem and I realized that the complexity of my solution was higher than anticipated due to the fact that `Insert` for `List<T>` is O(n) (source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4(v=vs.110).aspx).

What I want is a data structure like

- Sequential container
- Has binary search method that works when elements are in order
- Better-than-O(n) insertion at an index
- O(1) to get number of elements in the container
- O(1) lookup by index

In other words, I want something like `List<T>` except faster insertion.

Comment: [LinkedList<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @MatthewCawley I don't think you can access an element by index in O(1) with `LinkedList<T>`. E.g. can't do `int median = LL[LL.Count/2];`

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure if it met all criteria, just putting it out there for discussion. Will be keen to see the answer when it arrives...

Comment: I don’t know that a data structure like this exists (sounds a bit implausible), but I guess weirder things have done. You might get better results on [CS.SE], since this doesn’t have much to do with .NET (there’s definitely no single built-in collection). Also, if you describe the algorithm that requires these properties, it might be possible to find an alternative.

Comment: (Details are pretty important in knowing if you can use a trie, for example, which kind of has O(1) lookup if your indexes are bounded.)

Comment: You say you need O(1) lookup by index, but your description suggests you're actually inserting elements in the middle to maintain some sort of order and don't mind that this changes the index of existing elements. So this requirement is weird. If all you need is a container that can efficiently maintain sorted elements with better-than-O(n) insertion, `SortedSet<T>` works. It does not allow duplicates, but that can be worked around by storing a wrapper type that includes `T` and the count and incrementing that count if the element is already present.

Comment: Is it possible to end up with duplicates in the list, or can you guarantee you won't see the same value twice? Do you need to specify the index, or do you expect things are sorted based on the value of the item?

Comment: sounds like an x-y problem here. what are you hoping to solve?

Comment: The reason describing your algorithm is important, by the way (per Ryan) isn't merely because some operations might be faster if your input satisfies certain conditions, but because it matters quite a bit what *exact* operations are important for your algorithm. For example, while `LinkedList` allows O(1) insertion, it typically performs badly in every other way due to locality of reference issues -- and that's ignoring the fact that you can't index it. I suggested `SortedSet<T>`, but `Dictionary<T, int>` might be even better if you really just need a simple multiset -- and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to end up with duplicates in the list, or can you guarantee you won't see the same value twice? Do you need to specify the index, or do you expect things are sorted based on the value of the item?

If you know there won't be duplicates, or you don't want to store the value twice when there are duplicates, and your index is based entirely on putting the item in the correct position based on its value, you could look at the [`SortedSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx) type.

If there might be duplicates, but you want to specify the value manually, you can look at a [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx), where the `TKey` values are your integer indexes.

If you can't meet either of those conditions, you're stuck implementing your own type. The good news is you don't have to start from scratch. The [`LinkedList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) type can get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly build in, but you can try it. Wintellect power collections has `BigList<T>` which will do the job.

https://powercollections.codeplex.com/

It has faster insertion at specific index compared to `List<T>`. I can't tell you the exact way it work but it keep some offsets around the elements, so in terms of memory it will be more epxensive.

You can find it also as nugget package.

**EDIT:**It has O(log n) indexed access as @Ryan has corrected me.

Comment: The `BigList<T>` in that library has O(log n) indexed access, not O(1).

Comment: Thanks for the correction, i could't find documentation about the data structures in wintellect and i've answered by memory. Do you have any url for the documentation, i can remember there was official documentation ?

Comment: It’s in the XML comment documentation. Codeplex doesn’t seem to have line numbers or support linking to lines, but it is mentioned in https://powercollections.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/PowerCollections/BigList.cs.

Comment: Thanks for the info ;]